# Android BitmapFactory.decodeResource() error, or alternative options for loading large LUTs

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, lookup-tables

I'm creating an image processing app that requires some quite large look up tables. Currently, I have the tables saved as .txt files in the resources/raw directory of the app, as a 3x4913 array of values (3 being for the R,G,B). Loading all of these (9) LUTs up as the application starts takes a very slow 25s or more.

My colleague suggested that I instead save the LUT data as images themselves, in png format, which I have done, producing 9 different images of width 1 and height 4913. I've placed them in the drawable folder and tried decoding them using BitmapFactory.decodeResource(), **which works for any other drawable without error**. When I do it with the LUT images and click 'View Bitmap' in the debugger, it says:

> "Error while evaluating expression: Method threw 'Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentExpression' exception"

I even tried using some BitmapFactory options but with the same result:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.outHeight = 4913;
options.outWidth = 1;

// Error here
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), lutIds[n], options);

bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4913);
```

Any suggestions? Or alternatively, any ideas how else I could quickly load the data on each application launch. The maximum value for each number is 255 so they can be stored in shorts.

Thanks!

*Note: The LUT pngs show up fine in any image viewing software*

Comment: "Loading all of these (9) LUTs up as the application starts takes a very slow 25s or more" -- code generate a Java class that contains the LUTs. Include that Java source in your app. "Any suggestions?" -- post the entire Java stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Turns out, it was all working okay and the only issue is that Android Studio refuses to show certain sized bitmaps during debugging, it seems. Rookie error!

For those who are interested, loading data from .txt file took around 28-30 seconds on my phone (Xperia Z3), whereas converting the data to pngs using python and loading the pngs instead takes a tiny 0.1 seconds!